# Symfony2 Entity ManyToMany Relation Data Structure

Tags: database, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following setup:

```
Entity: 'Customers'
Entity: 'Accounts'
```

Those entities are in a @ManyToMany relation.

So I have the following database tables:

```
customers
accounts
customers_accounts
```

Now I need to save data for each customer for each account. Example:

> There is one customer 'Tom'. Two accounts 'Ben' and 'Eric' are in charge of customer 'Tom'. Now I need to save whether or not account 'Ben' has already spoken to customer 'Tom'. Also I need to save the same status for account 'Eric'.

What's the best way to organise the database here? Best thing would be that there is an extra column in the table 'customers_accounts'. Is that possible? What other options are there?

Thanks for your help!

---

Just to show you how the entities are linked to each other:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="accounts", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customers_accounts")
 **/
protected $customers;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ManyToMany` you can't add additional fields in your junction table i.e `customers_accounts` , to have an additional fields for your junction table you have to tweak your mappings as create a junction entity which will point your customer and accounts entity in `ManyToOne` way and your customer and accounts entities will point back to your junction entity in a `OneToMany` way

```
        OneToMany                 OneToMany
      ----------->            <------------
Customer       CustomerHasAccounts       Accounts
      <----------             ------------>
        ManyToOne                ManyToOne
```

### Customer Entity

```
/**
 * Customer
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\CustomerHasAccounts", mappedBy="customers",cascade={"persist","remove"} )
     */
    protected $hasAccounts;

}
```

### Accounts Entity

```
/**
 * Accounts
 * @ORM\Table(name="accounts")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Accounts 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\CustomerHasAccounts", mappedBy="acccounts",cascade={"persist","remove"} )
     */
    protected $hasCustomers;

}
```

### CustomerHasAccounts Entity

```
/**
 * CustomerHasAccounts
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers_accounts")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CustomerHasAccounts
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\Accounts", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="acccount_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $acccounts;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NameSpace\YourBundle\Entity\Customer", cascade={"persist","remove"} , fetch="LAZY" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customers_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $customers;


    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string")
     */
    protected $status;

}
```

Comment: I see: So I have to implement a 'Customer -> CustomerAccountData <- Account' relation? And the CustomerAccountData holds customerID and accountID as foreign keys?

Comment: @Chris. see my updated answer i hope it will clear the concept

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I will test everything once I get to it (propably later today) and accept the answer in case everything turns out fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform your ManyToMany relation between your entities by a OneToMany-ManyToOne entity making the link between your 2 ManyToMany entities, this entity will have all the data related to this relation.

<kbd>Customer</kbd>

```
Class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CustomerAccount", mappedBy="societe", cascade={"Persist"})
     */
    private $customerAccounts;
}
```

<kbd>Account</kbd>

```
Class Account
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CustomerAccount", mappedBy="account", cascade={"Persist"})
     */
    private $customerAccounts;
}
```

<kbd>CustomerAccount</kbd>

```
Class CustomerAccount
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="customerAccounts")
     */
    private $societe;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Account", inversedBy="customerAccounts")
     */
    private $contact;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="alreadySpoken", type="boolean")
     */
    private $alreadySpoken;
}
```